# ¿Como alternar entre los distintos estilos de una fuente en CSS? (Google Fonts)

Tags: html, css, fuentes

Estoy agregando fuentes de Google Fonts, y estoy en esta situación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede ver, estoy usando la fuente Oswald y dentro de esa fuente añadí dos estilos distintos (Extra-light 200 y Medium 500). Mi duda es, como alterno entre estos dos estilos distintos en CSS? Porque por defecto me pone el último que añadí (Medium 500)

Comment: ¿Esto ayuda: [font-weight](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight)?

Answer (score 0):

Así como usas para negrita `bold`, para Google Fonts, usas el número correlativo al tipo de fuente, por ejemplo:
Usa:

```
p {
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dentro de tu css debes utilizar font-family: (nombre de la letra seleccionada);
te adjunto un ejemplo:

```css
#contenedor{
width: 50%;
background-color: aliceblue;
font-size: 40px;
font-family: Langar;
text-align: center;
border-radius: 90px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ruta/archivo.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Langar"> <! -- este link rel te conecta a la página de google fonts para que puedas acceder desde el CSS, justo donde pone family=Comfortaa está tu fuente que en este caso es comfortaa -->
</head>
<body>
<div id="contenedor">
  <p> Un ejemplito </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```